# MinGW linking problem

Tags: c++, mingw, linker-errors

I have a linking problem with MinGW. These are the calls:

```
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import
    -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -mthreads -Wl -Wl,-subsystem,windows
    -o debug/Simulation.exe debug/LTNetSender.o debug/main.o debug/simulation.o
    debug/moc_simulation.o  -L'c:/Programmieren/Qt/4.5.2/lib' -lmingw32
    -lqtmaind -LC:\Programmieren\Qt\boost_1_39_0\distrib\lib
    -LC:\Programmieren\MinGW\lib -llibboost_system-mgw34-mt -llibws2_32
    -lQtSqld4 -lQtGuid4 -lQtNetworkd4 -lQtCored4

C:\Programmieren\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\
    ld.exe: cannot find -llibws2_32
```

The MinGW library directory is included in the library path and `libws2_32.a` is in this directory. Why isn't the linker finding the library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the linker command should be -lws2_32. The "lib" and ".a" is filled in automatically.

Comment: the thing that is funny: I need the lib for libboost_system-mingw32-mt. Without the lib, I get a linker error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using Boost anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you should be using `-llibws2_32`? The `lib` and the `.a` are added automagically by the linker.

Try it with `-lws2_32` instead. My version of `ld` works with that:

```
pax@daemonspawn> ld -llibm
ld: cannot find -llibm

pax@daemonspawn> ld -lm
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```